# Number of "intersecting" subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $V$ be an $n$-dim vector space over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $A$ be a $k$-dim subspace of $V$. I want to know the number of $k$-dim subspaces $B$ of $V$ such that $dim(A\cap B)=i$.

My idea is that the number is $$\frac{(q^k-1)(q^k-q)\cdots (q^k-q^{i-1})}{(q^i-1)(q^i-q)\cdots (q^i-q^{i-1})}\cdot\frac{(q^n-q^i)\cdots (q^n-q^{k-1})}{(q^{k-i}-1)\cdots (q^{k-i}-q^{k-i-1})},$$

where $(q^k-1)(q^k-q)\cdots (q^k-q^{i-1})$ is the number of ways to choose a basis (with order) inside $A$ of the intersecting $i$-dim subspace, and then we divide by $(q^i-1)(q^i-q)\cdots (q^i-q^{i-1})$ to eliminate the repetitions, as there are so many ways to choose a basis that spans the same intersecting subspace. Similar for the remaining terms.

Am I correct? Is there a simpler way to represent the number?